# How can i make bullets list in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I was trying to convert the html tags from php to excel using `PHPExcel`, everything is going alright except that I can't find how to make bulletted list. is this feature exist in PHPExcel? i already scan some of the documentary of PHPExcel but i can't find anything about bullets.

i want to place the bulletted inside one cell

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply want a string containing newline characters, and then to set the cell to wrap

```
$value = "• Foo\n• Bar";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A10', $value);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getRowDimension(10)
    ->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A10')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```